# Django custom template tags not loading

Tags: django, pycharm, templatetags

I'm having trouble using custom template tags in my Django 1.8 project. This is what happens:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag: 'custom_foo'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    <...>
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'custom_foo'
```

My folders look like:

```
my_app
|---templatetags
    |---__init__.py
        myapp_extras.py
```

And `myapp_extras.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def custom_foo():
    return 'bar'
```

I'm using PyCharm5 for development.
Must be missing something.

My base.html template has `{% load myapp_extras %}` at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've registered `custom_foo()` as a filter, try registering it as a tag according to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/ , for example:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

class BarNode(template.Node):
  def render(self, context):
    return 'bar'

@register.tag
def custom_foo(parser, token):
  return BarNode()
```

Comment: That helps. But `render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`, so `def render(self, somevar)`. Now I have to try to figure out why (or rewrite) django_hijack so the tags work. Is this a recent change in 1.8?

Comment: And I see what it is. django-hijack has an error in their docs. The error I'm getting is a result of using a tag implementation for a filter, which won't work. Thanks @Adrian!